# Default Web Application URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

Currently, the default url for my sample application is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/SpringMVC/
```

Is it possible for my to access it through below url ?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename the war file to `ROOT.war` . Then delete (or rename) the default ROOT tomcat directory and start tomcat.